# JavaScript Session storage variable on another page

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm rather new to JavaScript and I would love some help getting this code to work. I've looked at multiple other posts talking about session storage as well as if/else statements and still can't seem to figure it out.

I have a page, lets call it page 1 and it has 3 links, "red" "green" and "blue".

When you click on any of these links its function sets a session storage variable 'colorVar' to the color chosen and then redirects to a page called page 2.

As page 2 loads, the window.onload action is used to start a function according to the variable set on page 1. In this case the function that starts on page 2 simply displays "Your color is ____!".

Heres the code:

```
<!-- [This is Page 1] -->

<a href="Page2.html" onclick="colorRed()">Set color to red</a>
<a href="Page2.html" onclick="colorBlue()">Set color to blue</a>
<a href="Page2.html" onclick="colorGreen()">Set color to green</a>

<script>

function colorRed() {
      sessionStorage.setItem("colorVar", "red"); 
}
function colorBlue() {
     sessionStorage.setItem("colorVar", "blue");
}
function colorGreen() {
     sessionStorage.setItem("colorVar", "green"); 
}
</script>

<!-- [This is Page 2] -->

<script>
window.onload = sessionStorage.colorVar + 'Write()';

function redWrite() {
    document.write("Your color is red!")
}

function blueWrite() {
    document.write("Your color is blue!")
}

function greenWrite() {
   document.write("Your color is green!")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated. See more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't session storage still work if 'Page 2' was opened in the same tab as Page 1, or does this also cause a new session to be initiated?

Comment: It wouldn't work. You should use local storage.

Comment: Why don't you give the variable per URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `sessionStorage` as as query string at `href` of `<a>` element; use `location.search` at `window.onload` event at `Page2.html`

Page1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="Page2.html" data-color="red" onclick="color(this)">Set color to red</a>
  <a href="Page2.html" data-color="blue" onclick="color(this)">Set color to blue</a>
  <a href="Page2.html" data-color="green" onclick="color(this)">Set color to green</a>

  <script>
    function color(elem) {
      event.preventDefault();
      sessionStorage.setItem("colorVar", elem.dataset.color);
      location.href = elem.href + "?colorVar=" + sessionStorage.getItem("colorVar");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

at Page2.html

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.write("Your color is " + location.search.split("=").pop())
}
</script>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/eNVXr4ElXRzrxlZ7EY0a?p=preview

Comment: This is by far the best answer to the problem.  Good work!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Clearly the *[answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034688/484732)* is much better than what i provided.  I'll leave this here for future viewers - maybe the way I phrased things help someone sometime.

---

Taylor,

Two things.

1. `sessionStorage()` is unique to each page/tab.  [From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) "**Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated**"
2. `window.onload` is [expecting a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).  You're just concatenating a string.

If you find a different way to pass information from one page to another (you could stuff it in the URL) your new color function should look something like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = writeColor(sessionStorage.colorVar);

function writeColor(color) {
  document.write("Your color is " + color + "!")
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set window.onload to be a string; you have to point it directly to a function.

I would suggest creating a new function (call it writeColor) that contains `if` statements based on the value of `sessionStorage.colorVar`; then you can do `window.onload=writeColor;`

Alternately, change your window.onload line to `window.onload = window[sessionStorage.colorVar + 'Write'];` which will grab your function from the global scope and assign it to window.onload.