# Getting Value of one Tag of page and storing it to another tag of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was finding difficult to get the value of tag of one page and use that value in another page. Note that the value are getting dynamically in the page. one part is static value and other part is dynamically coming. It is coming when we start a session. These two values are separated by pipe(|). Below is the example:
site 1:

```
<select name="ETD" id="nBFDXS">
    <option value="xxx|12341234123412341234123421341234123412" >abc </option>
</select></td>
```

xxx is the static value which is separated by pipe then the dynamic values.

now I want to store this value and use this value in another page. which has same code as above. How i can do this?
TIA

Comment: Did you start implementing a solution that did not work?

Comment: <script>
    var tt;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      tt = $('#nBFDXS').val();   
   })
   </script>

Comment: you can save the value in global `window` object, or you can storage like `local/session Storage, cookies etc`, you can also use url query params, hash etc.

Comment: _"use this value in another page"_ Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? What is "another page"?

Comment: @Vikramaditya : Any you provide me with examples

Comment: @guest271314 : I am using this value in another page where it is using same value. i am looking to enter the value in the page. Actually every time it is creating new value.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('code', $('#nBFDXS').val()); as the option is single.

Comment: See [JavaScript Session storage variable on another page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034647/javascript-session-storage-variable-on-another-page), [Can the mechanism that loads the worker in Shared Web Workers be modified?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938039/can-the-mechanism-that-loads-the-worker-in-shared-web-workers-be-modified), [Can we refer to javascript variables across webpages in a browser session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146595/can-we-refer-to-javascript-variables-across-webpages-in-a-browser-session)