# Set dynamic variable to an ajax XMLHttpRequest instead of getting value from onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I´ve come across a script which I need to modify but I don't know how, what I need is to set on page load it reads the value and toss the result that is coming from a database.

The code I will paste is working and does fetch the result from the DB from the select form, now how I can I set a variable that is loaded when page loads and get the result from the DB?

have 3 pages I depend on
1 datalyer page its all good
2 php page
3 html page. here hast the script below, I'm using select option for Peter Griffin  his value I will like it to be variable member.

I said onload because on page 1, when ever user surf through the web the pages refresh then new data I send and I need the result of the DB based on the variable.

```
  <script>

/** page one  where member is a value that is fetch from a layer
  var member = google_tag_manager["GTM-x"].dataLayer.get('ContractNumber');
```

console.log(member);  **/

```
  function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","elsewhere.php?q="+str,true);
    console.log(str);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>

 <body>


  <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="variable member">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
<option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>

 <br>
 <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

 </body>
```

as I said before this code is working, but instead of using the select how can I tell it on pageload read the variable X and fetch result, in this case "0000004445" is what I need, the variable will be dynamic so "0000004445" can become anything.

Comment: Would it be simpler just add the data at the server-side before the page loads?

Comment: Try using  Local storage to save dynamic variable values and fetch the data from db using that local storage variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `selected` attribute at the `<option>` element where the the value should be retrieved, attach `load` event to `window` and within `load` handler call `showUser()` with `document.querySelector("select[name=users]").value` as argument

```js
function showUser(str) {
  console.log(str);
}

onload = function() {
  showUser(document.querySelector("select[name=users]").value)
}
```

```html
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="0000004445" selected>Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
<option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>
```

Comment: select value won't be available after page reload.

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail Not following what you mean?

Comment: almust what i needed, but "0000004445" is a number i set manually, the value must be dynamic since is like an ID , so example <option value="somevaribale" selected>Peter Griffin</option> is this possible?

Comment: @walteralexander You can set the `value` of the `<option>` to any valid valid, and set `selected` attribute at any `<option>` element

Comment: @guest271314 what i am understanding from question is that he wants to persist the value selected from select input after page reload, select value will reset so what i am suggesting  him is to save the selected value in local storage for further use. (pardon me if i ddn't understood the question properly )

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail Where are "reload" and "persist" mentioned at original Question? No worries, your interpretation of the Question could well be consistent with what OP is asking. Have you considered posting an Answer?

Comment: @guest271314 "i can i set a variable the be loaded when page loads" - this means persisting to me and "pageload" means reload. As i mentioned in my previous comment also question is not in best language and i might have interpreted differently, but i feel he wants to persists value after page reload and display data according to the value selected.

Comment: this is my scenario, the variable will be another variable that is been fecth from a datalyer       ...... var member = google_tag_manager["GTM-xxxxxx"].dataLayer.get('ContractNumber');
  console.log(member);        , now meber is what cantains (0000004445), i asid onload since is an ajax page when the page load it get the variable "member" so, how can i set that when the script side when it gets the variable meber it uses it to request the data from the DB

Comment: @walteralexander Not following the description at comment. Can you include the full code with descriptions at original Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i did it already, please let me know if i explained myslef correctly and did not cause any misunderstanding

Comment: @walteralexander Do you mean that `showUser` function is within an HTML `document` that is opened after "page one"?

Comment: yes,, now if i can turn showUser in  a full js file(page) will also be better for me

Comment: Is the second HTML document opened by the user clicking a link at the first HTML document?

Comment: Thanks for yet another meaningless "downvote". What is the issue with the Answer?

Comment: i did not downvoted you, yes the date is fetch from the 1 page it sends it to the 2page html. which query agains the php page

Comment: @walteralexander That comment is directed to the user whom cast the meaningless "downvote". They know who they are. And only they know the manufactured or lack of reason for their "vote".

Comment: @walteralexander You can pass the value from the first HTML document to the second HTML document using query string parameters, then parse `location.search` at the second HTML document, see [JavaScript Session storage variable on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034647/javascript-session-storage-variable-on-another-page). Note, `sessionStorage` portion of Answer is not necessary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163747/discussion-between-walter-alexander-and-guest271314).